# How do I find vertices in a graph that have one out degree but no in degrees?

Tags: r, igraph

I have an undirected network of papers that all cite each other. I want to find the papers/nodes/vertices that have one 'out degree' (that is, they cite one paper) but no 'in degrees' (they are not cited by anyone).

This seems like a really simple question but I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere on stack overflow/ the internet..

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: To give an example, the edge list with a single in-degree and no out-degree looks like this:

```
Paper1 -> Paper3
Paper2 -> Paper3
Paper4 -> Paper1
Paper1 -> Paper4
Paper5 -> Paper1
Paper6 -> Paper4
```

In this example, I just want to know the identity of Paper5 and Paper6, which cite one paper but are not cited. It doesn't need to be in an edge list (although it's also fine if it is). So desired output is:

```
identified_papers <- c("Paper5", "Paper6")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a relatively straightforward task, once you have your data in a suitable format, e.g. an edgelist:

```
from <- c("Paper1", "Paper2", "Paper4", "Paper1", "Paper5", "Paper6")
to <- c("Paper3", "Paper3", "Paper1", "Paper4", "Paper1", "Paper4")
edgelist <- cbind(from, to)

> edgelist
     from     to      
[1,] "Paper1" "Paper3"
[2,] "Paper2" "Paper3"
[3,] "Paper4" "Paper1"
[4,] "Paper1" "Paper4"
[5,] "Paper5" "Paper1"
[6,] "Paper6" "Paper4"
```

Using `igraph` one can generate a graph from `edgelist`

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_edgelist(edgelist)
```

Use the `degree`-function in order to get the degree and specify whether to count in- or outdegree by setting the `mode` parameter:

```
> degree(g, mode = "in")
  Paper1 Paper3 Paper2 Paper4 Paper5 Paper6 
     2      2      0      2      0      0 

> degree(g, mode = "out")
  Paper1 Paper3 Paper2 Paper4 Paper5 Paper6 
     2      0      1      1      1      1
```

From there one can combine query conditions inside `which` in order to fit the requirements and extract the corresponding paper using `names`:

```
hits <- which(degree(g, mode = "in") == 0 & degree(g, mode = "out") == 1)
identified_papers <- names(hits)

> identified_papers
  [1] "Paper2" "Paper5" "Paper6"
```

I hope this helps.